# how to use foreach loop when creating array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach

I am creating an array, named `$subArray`. This array has to be filled with `$child->getName() => $child`, gotten from a XML document.

```
$subArray = array(
  foreach($person->children() as $child){
    $child->getName() => $child;
  }
);
```

But this doesn't seem to work, as I cannot use the `=>` when using `array_push`, and I cannot use a foreach loop inside an array. How do I solve this?

This is my whole function:

```
function get_xml_arr($xmlURL){

  $xml=simplexml_load_file($xmlURL) or die ("XML not found");

  $array = array();

  foreach($xml->person as $person){
    $subArray = array(
      foreach($person->children() as $child){
        $child->getName() => $child;
      }
    );
    array_push($array, $subArray);
  }

  return $array;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  $child->getName() as index of array in such way

```
$subArray = array();
foreach($xml->person as $person) {
   foreach($person->children() as $child) 
      $subArray[$child->getName()] = $child;
   $array[] = $subArray;
}
```

Comment: Ah, very nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: don't mention it. Good luck!